# Create input arrows in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm wondering if is possible to create some sort of notation to indicate inputs for a graph in networkx / Python.

For example, taking the image presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133479/how-to-draw-directed-graphs-using-networkx-in-python), supposed I want to be able to identify sources and sinks. I would be interested in creating a representation such as:

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: As a side note, the new version of networkx has the implementation of real arrows: [example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_directed.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-drawing-plot-directed-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) functionality does exactly what you want. (See also the [annotate intro](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html#annotations-tutorial))

Given the example you linked, you could just add the following to annotate selected nodes. (It depends on the positions dictionary `pos` to know where the nodes are located).

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("3", xy=pos.get('B'), xytext=(0, 40), textcoords='offset points',
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.15),  
    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="cyan"))
ax.annotate("4", xy=pos.get('F'), xytext=(0, 40), textcoords='offset points',
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.15),
    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="cyan"))
```

[image: example networkx with annotation]

So that this answer is self-contained, Full code including [linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20133763):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(
    [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('E', 'C'), ('E', 'F'),
     ('B', 'H'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'G')])

val_map = {'A': 1.0,
           'D': 0.5714285714285714,
           'H': 0.0}
values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]

# Specify the edges you want here
red_edges = [('A', 'C'), ('E', 'C')]
edge_colours = ['black' if not edge in red_edges else 'red'
                for edge in G.edges()]
black_edges = [edge for edge in G.edges() if edge not in red_edges]

# Need to create a layout when doing
# separate calls to draw nodes and edges
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), 
                       node_color = values, node_size = 500)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=red_edges, edge_color='r', arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=black_edges, arrows=False)

# add annotations for selected nodes.
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("3", xy=pos.get('B'), xytext=(0, 40), textcoords='offset points',
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.15),  
        bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="cyan"))
ax.annotate("4", xy=pos.get('F'), xytext=(0, 40), textcoords='offset points', 
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.15),  
        bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="cyan"))

plt.show()
```

Comment: I though there was some way to do it directly with the networkx api.