# Networkx: arrows, ploting

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I need to change the default arrow style for digraphs on networkx. I've read something about matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle, but I am too new coding and even newer in python, so I did not understand at all. My current code is:

```
G=nx.DiGraph()
n=len(C)
print(n)    
for i in range(n):
    G.add_node(i)

for i in nodos_usuarios:
    for j in nodos_cri:
        if Y[i,j].x==1:
            G.add_edge(i,j)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
x=G.node()
y=G.edges()
elist = edges
print(x)
print("")
print(y)
print("")
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, label="ciudades",size=0.1)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elist, edge_color='green', width=3, label="S") 
plt.legend(fontsize = 'medium')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig("Red.png")
plt.show()
```

Y is a matrix related to the graph G. My current output is:
[Ugly graph - Ugly arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHvNI.png)

So I need help to change this arrow style to the classical arrow that we all know. Is there someone could help me to do this more easily?

Comment: are you using a recent version of networkx? [https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/release/release_2.1.html](v2.1 release notes) indicate when it was overhauled

Comment: I guess not, how can I update my actual version of networkx using pip?

Comment: I updated the version, now how can I use  the arrow style?

Comment: I think that any version before 2.1 doesn't have the new arrow style. Which one are you using? You can check by typing this on command line:  `python -c "import networkx; print(networkx.__version__)"`

Comment: To update with pip, you need to explicitly use the `--upgrade` flag (with pip install), otherwise it keeps whatever version you had before, if there was a version installed

Answer (score 0):

Networkx has several attributes that you can use to modify your `draw_networkx_edges`.  It looks like you've set the `width` to be disproportionate with the size of the plot.  Without you're data, I can't reproduce, but if you reduce `width=3` to something smaller or the overall size to something larger (in proportion to the width of the edges you should get a nicer looking graph.

Docs on [networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated./networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html?highlight=draw%20network%20edges#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges).  See `width` where the default is set to `1.0` as opposed to your override of `3.0`.

Using a simple example from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133479/how-to-draw-directed-graphs-using-networkx-in-python) source:

```
#draw with `width=1.0`
```

[image]

```
#draw with `width=3.0`
```

[image]

If you also consider your node size in this code `nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, label="ciudades",size=0.1)` (the `0.1`) it is very small.

#### Changing Arrow Heads:

`draw_networkx_edges()` also has attributes for `arrows` which is default set to `True` and `arrowstyle` which provides for optional arrow head styles as set by [`matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html).  You can do something like this:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G, pos, 
    edgelist=elist, 
    edge_color='green', 
    width=3, 
    label="S",
    arrowstyle='-|>')  #<-- This is the "CurvedFilledB" class
```

In the docs for `ArrowStyle` you can simply pass the attribute characteristics you'd like to modify into the `draw_networkx_edges` code.  Without your data used to generate your image, it's difficult to tell what combination of these will provide the best result - easy enough to plug in different variables and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, that advice makes my plot better, but what about the arrows?, I still have the ugly arrows in my graph, do you know how to fix it? greetings.

Comment: The correct link for the first URL posted is https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html?highlight=draw%20network%20edges#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges (there was an extraneous period in the URL).