# how to plot a networkx graph using the (x,y) coordinates of the points list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have points as x,y and I want to plot my graph using the (x,y) coordinates of my points list  so that I can see the axis. here are my code and photo of the graph

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def add_edge_to_graph(G,e1,e2,w):
   G.add_edge(e1,e2,weight=w) 

G=nx.Graph()
points=[(1, 10), (8, 10), (10, 8), (7, 4), (3, 1)] #(x,y) points
edges=[(0, 1, 10), (1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 25), (0, 3, 3), (3, 4, 8)]#(v1,v2, weight)

for i in range(len(edges)):
       add_edge_to_graph(G,points[edges[i][0]],points[edges[i][1]],edges[i][2])
       
     
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos=pos,node_color='k')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=1500)  # draw nodes and edges
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos)  # draw node labels/names
# draw edge weights
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
plt.axis()
plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/criYx.png

Comment: Do you want that your graph is drawn using the (x,y) coordinates of your points list? Or do you just want to switch on the axis with ticks?

Comment: Have u checked that the ticks and labels are set on ?

Comment: @Sparky05  yes, i want to draw it using the (x,y) coordinates

Comment: @Henry Mont: yes

Comment: @Sparky05 :for example, i want it to be something like this https://imgur.com/8OqiVtw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def add_edge_to_graph(G, e1, e2, w):
    G.add_edge(e1, e2, weight=w)


G = nx.Graph()
points = [(1, 10), (8, 10), (10, 8), (7, 4), (3, 1)]  # (x,y) points
edges = [(0, 1, 10), (1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 25), (0, 3, 3), (3, 4, 8)]  # (v1,v2, weight)

for i in range(len(edges)):
    add_edge_to_graph(G, points[edges[i][0]], points[edges[i][1]], edges[i][2])

# you want your own layout
# pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
pos = {point: point for point in points}

# add axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_color='k', ax=ax)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=1500, ax=ax)  # draw nodes and edges
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos)  # draw node labels/names
# draw edge weights
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels, ax=ax)
plt.axis("on")
ax.set_xlim(0, 11)
ax.set_ylim(0,11)
ax.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)
plt.show()
```

#### Result

[image: Figure with axes on and right positions]

## Backround

For the axis, I used `plt.axis("on")` as already suggested above together with [How to make x and y axes appear when using networkx and matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994061/how-to-make-x-and-y-axes-appear-when-using-networkx-and-matplotlib)

Additionaly, I replaced the `spring_layout` with the positions in your `points` list.

Comment: @Faisal: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and I would recommend to do the general tour. E.g. you could (have) edited your question to clarify your points and (after you collect some rep) you can also directly include figures in your question.

Comment: The line `nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos)` should change to `nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)` to mention the current `ax`. Otherwise, it would cause errors if you're drawing with multiple axes.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to turn axis on with :

```
limits = plt.axis("on")
```

So that you're able to use draw with axis.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use networkx, but quite handy if you quickly want to visualize points and see the edges.

## sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample of edges where each node comprises of an x and y coordinate.
edges = [((84, 96), (93, 20)), ((93, 20), (94, 42)), ((94, 42), (98, 88))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for edge in edges:
    x = [edge[0][0], edge[1][0]]
    y = [edge[0][1], edge[1][1]]
    ax.plot(x, y, '-o')
```

## sample output:

[image]