# Plot networkx with assigned coordinates

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to run the following code to plot networkx graph but it gives me type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. May you help me with that?

```
pos = [[6.886709112999999, 50.50618938]]
nodes = ['866','144']
edges = [['866', '144']]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the positions for [`draw_networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx) you should supply a dictionary of positions (x,y):

> pos (dictionary, optional) – A dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values. If not specified a spring layout positioning will be computed. See networkx.drawing.layout for functions that compute node positions.

You can take a look here ([how to plot a networkx graph using the (x,y) coordinates of the points list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986306/how-to-plot-a-networkx-graph-using-the-x-y-coordinates-of-the-points-list)) for a recent example.
Or with your small example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

pos = {'866':[6.886709112999999, 0], '144': [50.50618938, 0]}
nodes = ['866','144']
edges = [['866', '144']]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

The type error you observed, is probably caused by networks trying to call your `pos` list with the nodes as index, e.g. `pos['866']`.