# How to plot a networkx graph using the (x,y) coordinates and edges (v1,v2) of the points list from a csv file

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have (x,y) coordinates and edge connections in a csv file. I want to plot my graph using the (x,y) coordinates and edge connections using **csv import**. Here Iam attaching the sample csv table format and my expected output?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using this to make the inputs from your `.csv` :

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval

with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",") # <-- adjust the sep if needed
    rows = list(reader)

points = [literal_eval(row["xy"]) for row in rows]
edges = [(literal_eval(row["v1v2"]) + (int(row["w"]),)) for row in rows]
```

Then you can use/readapt @*Sparky05*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64987049/16120011).

Output :

[image]

Comment: What would be the code if we don't have node id's, only coordinates as edge connections? Instead of node id's, coordinates to coordinates as v1v2 in the previously mentioned table. for eg. v1v2 as ((1,10), (8,10)),  ((8,10), (10,8)),  ((10,8), (7,4)),  ((1,10), (7,4)), ((7,4), (3,1)).