# Network graph customize from csv file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, networkx

I want to plot a network graph in python from CSV file, where there will be 3 types of networks connected . Want to customize and access based on attributes. Can anyone help me?Data looks like this , 3 graphs required in a plot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK9E8.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pls. refer to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section on how to ask questions here and [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [how to draw directed graphs using networkx in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133479/how-to-draw-directed-graphs-using-networkx-in-python) for the rendering, just use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html to read your data.