# How do I create a ego-network like the picture that I given below? I can get this far only

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

user_input = list(map(int, input("Enter the edges you want to plot: ").split()))
print("The edges are: ", user_input)
G = nx.Graph()

for x in user_input:
    if (x<len(user_input)):
        G.add_edge(x, x+1)

ego = user_input[0]
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color="lavender",
        arrows=True, arrowstyle='-|>',
        node_size=800, with_labels=True)

options = {"node_size": 1200, "node_color": "r"}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[ego], **options)
plt.show()
```

I want to create like the picture but I can not do it. And also, the numbers of edges is given by the user.
[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5h5f.png)

and I am getting like this. [This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpaBT.png)

I am hoping the user can give multiple edges and they will be projected like the image.

Comment: Please, please, don't post the same question twice. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75588086/edit) your previous question and add missing information, including a concrete list as input for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input essentially just seems to be getting a list of the nodes rather than which nodes should be joined by edges. Instead (based on, e.g., [this post and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133479/how-to-draw-directed-graphs-using-networkx-in-python)). You could create a script (called, e.g., `network.py`) containing:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get pairs of nodes that define the edges
user_input = input("Enter pairs of joined nodes separated by commas, e.g., 1 2, 1 3, 1 4:\n").split(",")

G = nx.Graph()

# add nodes
nodes = []
for edge in user_input:
    for node in edge.split():
        if int(node) not in nodes:
            nodes.append(int(node))
            G.add_node(int(node))

# add edges
for edge in user_input:
    G.add_edge(*[int(e) for e in edge.split()])

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color="lavender",
        arrows=True, arrowstyle='-|>',
        node_size=800, with_labels=True)

options = {"node_size": 1200, "node_color": "r"}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[nodes[0]], **options)
plt.show()
```

Then run this with:

```bash
python network.py
```

and input:

```
1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 2 3, 3 4, 3 6, 4 5, 6 5
```

to produce the graph you want.

[image]